# C# [i, j] add the min "j" values ​of matrix to the new array?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, matrix

[i, j] add the biggest values ​​of matrix to  j the new array 
its here:

But smallest not working.. 
Min values in "j" (not working)

```
for (int i = 0; i < olay; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < state; j++)
        {
            if (minimax[i] > matris[i, j])
            {
                minimax[i] = matris[i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < minimax.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + 1 + ". MINIMAX " + minimax[i]);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Max VALUES IN "J" (WORKING)

```
   for (int i = 0; i < olay; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < state; j++)
            {
                if (maximax[i] < matris[i, j])
                {
                    maximax[i] = matris[i, j];
                }
            }
        }

        /* Olaylar icin en yuksek State degerleri */
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < maximax.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + 1 + ". MAXIMAX " + maximax[i]);
        }
```

Output console: 
IMG Lınk: https://pasteboard.co/IKKQlet.jpg

Comment: You aren't computing the smallest (min).

Comment: Is there any exception or is it not working as intended?

Comment: i think you need to put initial matrix value to matrimax array. Can you please show what output you are getting on console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values in your arrays are 0.
To calculate the minimum value in each column and write it to an array you can do something like this:

```
    var resultArray = new int[rowLength];
    var matrix = new int[rowLength, columnLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
    {
        // you have to set the first value as a minimum and after that compare
        resultArray[i] = matrix[i, 0];

        for (int j = 1; j < columnLength; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i, j] < resultArray[i])
            {
                resultArray[i] = matrix[i, j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check the links: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-element-of-each-row-and-each-column-in-a-matrix/